# Google Play Services makes gradle to ignore proguard config

Tags: android, google-play-services, proguard

I'm working on Google Sign In option in my application. I used [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating) for that.

So not my config looks like this:

Top level gradle file:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    jcenter()
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.5.0'
    classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:1.5.0'
  }
}
```

app.gradle file

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
   buildTypes {
      minifyEnabled true
      shrinkResources true
      proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
      signingConfig signingConfigs.release
  }
}

dependencies {
    // retrofit, twitter sdk, eventbus, support library, activeandroid
    // Google SignIn
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:8.3.0'
}
```

And the problem is that now app fails on start with exception that ActiveAndroid classes not found and during build I'm getting billions of messages (below). It looks like including google play services ignores my proguard rules. If I remove those dependencies, app builds well and starts without any error.

```
Note: com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite$SerializedForm accesses a method 'newBuilder()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'bos { bot newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'bov { bow newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'boy { boz newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'bpb { bpc newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'bpe { bpf newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'bph { bpi newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'bpk { bpl newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'ccc { ccd newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'ccg { cch newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'ccj { cck newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto { com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto$Builder newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto$ExtensionRange { com.google.protobuf.DescriptorProtos$DescriptorProto$ExtensionRange$Builder newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser { com.google.protobuf.TextFormat$Parser$Builder newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet { com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Builder newBuilder(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Field { com.google.protobuf.UnknownFieldSet$Field$Builder newBuilder(); }'
Note: ctb accesses a method 'isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context)' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.android.gms.common.GooglePlayServicesUtil { int isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(android.content.Context); }'
Note: ctb accesses a method 'getId()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v4.app.Fragment { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager$BackStackEntry { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v7.view.menu.BaseMenuPresenter { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v7.view.menu.ListMenuPresenter { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPresenter { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar$ExpandedActionViewMenuPresenter { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'boy { bxv getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'btf { bxv getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'btg { bxv getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'butterknife.internal.FieldResourceBinding { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'butterknife.internal.ViewBindings { int getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'bxb { bxv getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'ccb { bxv getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'ccf { bxv getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.activeandroid.Model { java.lang.Long getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.facebook.GraphRequestBatch { java.lang.String getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.facebook.Profile { java.lang.String getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.facebook.share.widget.CreateAppGroupDialog$Result { java.lang.String getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info { java.lang.String getId(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'm { int getId(); }'
Note: ctb accesses a method 'isLimitAdTrackingEnabled()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info { boolean isLimitAdTrackingEnabled(); }'
Note: ctb accesses a method 'getAdvertisingIdInfo(android.content.Context)' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient { com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info getAdvertisingIdInfo(android.content.Context); }'
Note: da accesses a method 'apply()' dynamically
Note: dfy accesses a declared field 'os' dynamically
Note: dfy accesses a method 'symlink(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)' dynamically
Note: gv accesses a method 'addLikelySubtags(java.util.Locale)' dynamically
Note: gw accesses a method 'getScript(java.lang.String)' dynamically
Note: gw accesses a method 'addLikelySubtags(java.lang.String)' dynamically
Note: retrofit.RestMethodInfo accesses a method 'value()' dynamically
      Maybe this is program method 'butterknife.Bind { int[] value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'butterknife.BindBool { int value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'butterknife.BindColor { int value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonFilter { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonGetter { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnore { boolean value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties { java.lang.String[] value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreType { boolean value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude { com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude$Include value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonManagedReference { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyDescription { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder { java.lang.String[] value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.annotation.JsonValueInstantiator { java.lang.Class value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.util.LinkedNode { java.lang.Object value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.DELETE { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.EncodedPath { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.EncodedQuery { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.Field { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.GET { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.HEAD { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.Header { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.Headers { java.lang.String[] value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.PATCH { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.POST { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.PUT { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.Part { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.Path { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.Query { java.lang.String value(); }'
      Maybe this is program method 'retrofit.http.RestMethod { java.lang.String value(); }'
Note: there were 25 classes trying to access annotations using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the annotation attributes
      (using '-keepattributes *Annotation*').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 35 classes trying to access generic signatures using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the signature attributes
      (using '-keepattributes Signature').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 6 classes trying to access enclosing classes using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the inner classes attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 1 classes trying to access enclosing methods using reflection.
      You should consider keeping the enclosing method attributes
      (using '-keepattributes InnerClasses,EnclosingMethod').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#attributes)
Note: there were 24 unresolved dynamic references to classes or interfaces.
      You should check if you need to specify additional program jars.
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclass)
Note: there were 42 accesses to class members by means of introspection.
      You should consider explicitly keeping the mentioned class members
      (using '-keep' or '-keepclassmembers').
      (http://proguard.sourceforge.net/manual/troubleshooting.html#dynamicalclassmember)
Note: you're ignoring all warnings!
```

Here is my proguard-rules.pro file:

```
#========================================
# General rules
#========================================
# General
-optimizations !code/simplification/arithmetic,!code/simplification/cast,!field/*,!class/merging/*
-optimizationpasses 5
-allowaccessmodification
-dontpreverify
-repackageclasses ''

-keepattributes *Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Signature

-keepclassmembers,allowoptimization enum * {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

#========================================
# ButterKnife
#========================================
-keep class butterknife.** { *; }
-dontwarn butterknife.internal.**
-keep class **$$ViewBinder { *; }

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <fields>;
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    @butterknife.* <methods>;
}

#========================================
# EventBus
#========================================
-keepclassmembers class ** {
    public void onEvent*(**);
}

#========================================
# Android support libraries
#========================================
-keep class android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v4.app.** { *; }
-dontwarn android.support.v7.**
-keep class android.support.v7.** { *; }
-keep interface android.support.v7.** { *; }

-keep class android.support.v8.renderscript.** {
    native <methods>;
}

#=======================================
# ActiveAndroid
#=======================================
-keep class com.activeandroid.** { *; }
-keep class com.activeandroid.**.** { *; }
-keep,allowobfuscation,allowshrinking,allowoptimization class * extends com.activeandroid.Model
-keep class * extends com.activeandroid.serializer.TypeSerializer

#=======================================
# Facebook SDK
#=======================================
-keep class com.facebook.** {
   *;
}

#=======================================
# Retrofit
#=======================================
-keep class com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-keep interface com.squareup.okhttp.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.squareup.okhttp.**

-dontwarn rx.**
-dontwarn retrofit.**
-dontwarn okio.**
-keep class retrofit.** { *; }
-keepclassmembers class * {
    @retrofit.http.* <methods>;
}

#=======================================
# Jackson JSON Serializer/Deserializer
#=======================================
-dontskipnonpubliclibraryclassmembers

-keepnames class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
-keepnames class org.codehaus.jackson.** { *; }
#-keep class com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
#-keep interface com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }
#-keep @interface com.fasterxml.jackson.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers public final enum org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility {
    public static final org.codehaus.jackson.annotate.JsonAutoDetect$Visibility *;
}

-keepclasseswithmembers class * {
    @com.fasterxml.jackson.* <fields>;
}

-dontwarn javax.xml.**
-dontwarn javax.xml.stream.events.**
-dontwarn com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.**

#=====================================
# Glide
#=====================================
-keep public class * implements com.bumptech.glide.module.GlideModule

#=====================================
# Google Play Services library
#=====================================
-keep class * extends java.util.ListResourceBundle {
    protected Object[][] getContents();
}

-keep public class com.google.android.gms.common.internal.safeparcel.SafeParcelable {
    public static final *** NULL;
}

-keepnames @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName class *
-keepclassmembernames class * {
   @com.google.android.gms.common.annotation.KeepName *;
}
-keepnames class * implements android.os.Parcelable {
   public static final ** CREATOR;
}
```

Comment: May sound silly, but have you tried cleaning and re-building your project?

Comment: Yes, sure. Also I tried move my proguard rules to default proguard rules, no changes.

Comment: And it works if you change minifyEnabled to false?

Comment: Hmmm, changing minifyEnabled and shrinkResources to false makes app run without exceptions, but `gradle clean assembleRelease` still has that output.

Comment: And if you just turn minifyEnabled to false it works? If so then you're going to have to go through your pro-guard file again and make sure your adding everything that is needed to run Google Play Services.

Comment: I've noticed some interesting Proguard issues with the latest gradle build tools revisions myself, after coming from `1.3.1`. Assuming you're not relying on the new vector drawable and databinding stuff, could you try and see what happens when you use `com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.1`?